# Is it possible in WordPress to test for an empty term or category?

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, testing, categories

I have a project that requires me to list out the available terms for each custom post type and indicate visually which of the terms/categories are empty via css/javascript. Is there a way to return a list of terms/categories and say add a class to the empty ones ? Thanks for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. First you get your terms using [get_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) (I'm assuming your cpt has associated taxonomy with it)

```
<?php 

$custom_terms = get_terms('my_taxonomy');

if (is_array($custom_terms) && !empty($custom_terms)) {
    # code what you want here...
} else{
    # code if your terms come empty...
}
```

This should do it.

EDIT

After `$custom_terms` variable do a `print_r($custom_terms);` to see what the variable holds. You should get an array filled with `stdClass Object`s, one for each category in this taxonomy.

So you can further do something like this:

```
foreach ($custom_terms as $term) {
    if ($term->count != 0) {
        print_r($term->name);
    }
}
```

This will show you names of non empty categories in your taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to replay. I tried the code and it seams to be working partially. It return all terms as if they are NOT empty, i am certain they are empty as they do not have any associated posts. Is there any way something (un)related else might be causing a false positive ?

Comment: I've added additional code to check if the term is empty or not. You just need to adapt this to your need (be it in a post query or elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks so much this does EXACTLY what i wanted by returning both the empty and non empty terms allowing me to add a class and affect interaction with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to query the terms with the WP_Term_Query class (to complement dingo_d's answer):

```
$args = array(
 'taxonomy'   => 'my_taxonomy',
 'hide_empty' => false
);
$custom_terms = new WP_Term_Query($args);
```

Then, this would be how to iterate over the terms:

```
foreach($custom_terms->terms as $term){
    if ($term->count != 0) {
        print_r($term->name);
    }
}
```

This is a very short and concise article on why you should now use WP_Term_Query:

https://medium.com/vunamhung/say-goodbye-to-get-terms-use-wp-term-query-db774df6d9ea