# How to Display A Line of Text if WordPress Category is empty?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display a line of text if a specific category (in this case: advisories) is empty, but the code I am trying to use does not display anything.

```
<?php   
if ( in_category( 'advisories' )->count > 0 ) {
echo test;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

**Solution**

```
$custom_terms = get_terms();
foreach ($custom_terms as $term) {
    if ($term->count != 0 && $term->name == "Uncategorized") {
        echo $term->name . " - blank" . '<br>';
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Hope this will helps you.
For more example, please visit

[get_terms Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

[WordPress to test for an empty term or category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098900/is-it-possible-in-wordpress-to-test-for-an-empty-term-or-category)

Comment: I tried this and it still did not display text  for the specific category "advisories" when the category is empty.

Comment: It's working please check properly and I updated the result that I've tried.

Comment: Sunil - Seems like there was a bug with WordPress, but it is working now. Thank You!

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$category = get_category($id);

$count = $category->category_count;

if( $count > $something ) {

   // stuff
}
```